# Vue component gets recreated after created method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I try to calculate the margin of an image to show it in the center of the page when the image dialog is ***created***. I calculate the margin in the component's ***created*** method and when I debug, I see that it is positioned correctly after my jquery margin set method. But when I continued the debug, the component is somehow rerendered without going into the created method and the margin of the image doesn't get set. I came accross this situation all the time when I try to set some variable in the created method and it always rerenders without going into the ***created*** block. Is there any way to prevent that? It is really annoying.

Here is my created block :

```
async created() {
    let self = this;

    $('.vodal.image-dialog').css('cursor', 'wait');

    $('.vodal.image-dialog').css('cursor', 'default');
    var margin = $(window).width() / 2 - $(".vodal.image-dialog .pop-up img").width() / 2;
    $(".vodal.image-dialog img").css('margin-left', margin);
    $(".vodal.image-dialog .pop-up img").show();

  },
```

UPDATE :

I solved this by simply giving the margin attribute with v-bind:style and get it from a computed property like this :

```
<img v-if="isEntitySaved()" v-bind:style="{'margin-left': margin + 'px'}"
      v-bind:src="image" class="blurred"/>
...
computed: {
    margin: function() {
      var imgClass = ''
      if(this.source == 'detail-main')
        imgClass = ".vodal.image-dialog .pop-up .main-image img"
      else
        imgClass = ".vodal.image-dialog .pop-up .side-image img"

      return $(window).width() / 2 - $(".vodal.image-dialog .pop-up ." + this.source + " img").width() / 2
    }
  }
```

But the problem continues, in another component I had it's template style 'display: none' initially. After some button is clicked, I want to show it so I set its style to 'display: block' in the **created** and **updated** methods, but again it gets displayed after the $.show method at the and of the created block but the components gets rerendered and disappears without going into the created or updated block. How can I solve this?

Comment: Oooof, why is there jQuery in your Vue app?

Answer (score 1):

`created` hook only gets's called once, you need to leverage the `updated` hook.

```js
export default {
  created() {
    this.updateStyle();
  },
  updated() {
    this.updateStyle();
  },
  methods: {
    updateStyle() {
      let self = this;

      $(".vodal.image-dialog").css("cursor", "wait");

      $(".vodal.image-dialog").css("cursor", "default");
      var margin =
        $(window).width() / 2 -
        $(".vodal.image-dialog .pop-up img").width() / 2;
      $(".vodal.image-dialog img").css("margin-left", margin);
      $(".vodal.image-dialog .pop-up img").show();
    },
  },
};
```

## Update

Because you use too much jQuery in Vue app.

The **fastest** way to solve your problem is simply force re-render like this

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      count: 0,
    };
  },
  updated() {
    // updated will guarantee to be called if you modify this.count
  },
  methods: {
    doSomething() {
      // do what ever you want
      // .......
      // At the end, make sure to call this
      this.count++;
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: I updated the question, can you check?